# Ubuntu 12.04 resolution stuck on 640x480

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, resolution, hdmi

I am new to Ubuntu and I was trying to get my HDMI enabled TV to work with my Ubuntu 12.04 computer and I installed a Nvidia driver using the "additional drivers" program. After that didn't work, I started playing around with the dual booted windows 7 on my computer. Now, I've never used that windows since I installed it so I was stripped down to bare minimum so I tried to adjust the resolution(as it was on lowest resolution) and tried to connect the HDMI, which didn't work. After that I came back to my Ubuntu installation only to find out that it is now stuck on 640x480 resolution. I tried to remove the driver that I installed again using the "additional drivers" program but that didn't help at all.

The error that showed up was -

**Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors**

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 63
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 64
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1366x768@60Hz (pass 1)

Any help would be appreciated as this is very annoying.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Been there today!  12.04 on a VGA output board.  Same error as yours.

Success came as follows:

1. Set up TV so that its PC input (VGA in this case) offers the TV's best ie 1368x768
   (and later, had to adjust TV's horiz and vert position to get the image fully on screen)
2. Boot Ubuntu and go through the above errors.  Just close that error window.
3. `cvt 1368 768 60`
   gives a modeline statement.  I'm not on that set up now so can't show that, but here's the one from the PC I'm on now:
   Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
4. `xrandr --newmode` [copy from the space after cvt Modeline output]
   eg
   xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
5. `xrandr`
   to see the extra in the list of modes available
6. `xrandr --addmode VGA1 [or whatever] 1368x768_60.00`
   which in my case not only made that new mode available on VGA1 but switched over to using it immediately. You might need an xrandr --output command

I believe, but haven't yet tried, that adding lines 4 and 6 to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf might make it happen after a restart.  I just put lines 4 and 6 in a desktop text document with name ending .sh, props that and make it executable.  After reboot, double click the document, choose RUN, and hopefully you have the desired resolution.  Now you can waste your time watching those TV recordings in proper full 16:9 display!

Best of luck

Apols if the code above is not 100% spot on.  It's from memory as I am not at the system in question.